# Very high delays when browsing samba share, how to speed up?

Tags: windows, samba, smb

I'm accessing a samba share from a windows 8.1 computer, and I have the problem that the latency is really high. Opening a file can take seconds. Opening windows file dialogs on a net path or net drive often crashes the program. And when I browse the share with Explorer, and move through the files with the cursor keys, it hangs for about a second for each file.

I already excluded the mapped network drive from Windows Defender, which sped it up a bit (it seemed to read each file for inspection). However, latency is still bad. Throughput, OTOH, is OK.

Most performance tips on the internet were concerned about increasing the throughput. I don't even know where to start to reduce the delays. Any ideas?

Some excerpts from the logs:

When highlighting a file in Explorer:

```
jason opened file path/to/file.txt read=No write=No (numopen=2)
jason closed file path/to/file.txt (numopen=0) NT_STATUS_OK
```

When connecting I get:

```
setup_new_vc_session: New VC == 0, if NT4.x compatible we would close all old resources.
```

but I don't know if that's actually an issue.

Comment: what kind of physical network interface are you using?

Comment: Currently Wifi, but the connection is good, and that's not the problem. I think I've found the solution, although I don't know how it works. Will post it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it, and the solution is a bit weird, so I'd appreciate some explanation in the comments :-).

I withheld a bit of information in the question, because I thought it was not important and didn't want people to only focus on that bit. What I'm actually doing is, I'm running samba as a non-privileged user on port 1445. Then I created a loop-back device in Windows, and created an ssh tunnel to bind my remote port 1445 (which is not accessible outside of the company's network) to the loopback's port 445. Oh, and I'm doing it over Wifi :-). So there are plenty of potential performance bottlenecks, but I didn't want everybody to point out e.g. the ssh tunnel as the problem, since I knew that was OK (and the performance was well otherwise).

It turns out, the loopback device was the problem. I found obscure tip on the net and tried it, and it worked. In the registry editor, I went to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\<GUID of the loopback device>
```

You can find the loopback device GUID by looking at all interfaces and comparing the IPAddress value.

I then created two keys, and rebooted:

```
TcpAckFrequency = 1 (DWORD)
TcpDelAckTicks = 0 (DWORD)
```

Afterwards, it is pretty snappy, and browsing the shares feels almost like browsing a local drive. I have to note that I think this is only remotely due to my obscure setup. The original site I got the tip from  (forgot the link) suggested that you apply this registry hack to your actual network device. As I'm not sure what it actually does, I wouldn't recommend doing that, but since I use this network interface only for Samba, it probably has no adverse effects on the rest of the system.